# Data not published on Azure Event hub when in large number

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I am using [EventHubProducerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.producer.eventhubproducerclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Producer_EventHubProducerClient__ctor_System_String_System_String_) class to publish messages on Azure Event Hub.
When I am trying to send a large amount of data, let's say 1000 messages one by one, this test case passes but I see only 400-500 (random number) on the Event hub dashboard. Here is the code.

```
public async Task TestEventHubPublishMessagesSequentially()
{
    var eventHubConnectionString = "XXXXX.CONNECTION STRING.XXXX";
    var eventHubName = "XXXXX.EVENT HUB NAME.XXXX";

    var messsage = "I am a message"
    int tobePublishCount = 2000;
    int publishCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tobePublishCount; i++)
    {
       var completeMessage = $"Index:{i}-message";
       var success = await PublishMessageSequentially(eventHubConnectionString, eventHubName, completeMessage);
       if (success)
       {
          publishCount++;
       }
    }

    Assert.Equal(2000, publishCount);
 }
      
 public async Task<bool> PublishMessageSequentially(string eventHubConnectionString, string eventHubName, string messageToPublish)
 {
     await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(eventHubConnectionString, eventHubName))
     {
        using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

        var data = new Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToPublish));

        if (eventBatch.TryAdd(data))
        {
           await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

However, If I try to publish them in the list, I can see all the data on the event hub.

```
   List<string> totalMessages = new List<string>();
   for (int i = 0; i < tobePublishCount; i++)
   {
      totalMessages.Add($"Index: {i}, I am a message");
   }
   await PublishMessageTogether(eventHubConnectionString, eventHubName, completeMessage);


   public async Task PublishMessageTogether(string eventHubConnectionString, string eventHubName, List<string> messagesToPublish)
   {
       await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(_eventHubsConnectionString, _eventHubName))
       {
         List<Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData> azureEventData = new List<Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData>>();
         foreach(var messageToPublish in messagesToPublish)
         {
            var eventData = new Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
               azureEventData.Add(eventData);
         }
         await producerClient.SendAsync(azureEventData);           
       }
       return publishCount;
    }
 }
```

I have no idea, what goes wrong, The only difference, I can see I am creating a new Object of EventHubProducerClient again and again, but I am disposing of it too. I thought Event hubs are designed to consume large data (millions per second). My Use case is I have to publish them one by one.

Comment: What part of test case fails?

Comment: Test cases are passing but when publishing sequentially 1000 messages, I see only 500-600 messages on Event hub.

Comment: Are you attempting to read back the events after publishing or just using the portal dashboard as an indicator?   How long are you waiting between publishes to check?   In the first sample, you're creating a new connection for each event that you're sending, and sending them one-by-one.   Each event is an independent unit that has to be processed by the service, and the dashboard also is a periodic snapshot.   It may take a bit longer to reflect your desired end state.

Comment: With respect to the first snippet, I'd strongly advise caching the producer between attempts;  by not doing so, you're creating a new connection to the Event Hubs service each call which is going to drastically reduce your throughput.

Comment: Can you also tell me how you are seeing the messages on Event Hub? Are you looking at the metrics or receiving actual events then counting?